# How to convert Word document into PDF using PHPWord

Tags: php, pdf, phpword

I am creating a Microsoft Word report using `PHPWord`. I basically start with a template and populate the fields and save it as a word report.

I would like to convert this report into a pdf file. I tried loading the generated doc file through PHPWord. However, when I save the pdf file, the formatting is all lost.

Here is the code I am using :

```
       require_once DOC_ROOT . '/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/bootstrap.php';

$path_to_tcpdf = DOC_ROOT . '/includes/plugins/TCPDF/'; // C:\xampp\htdocs\clients\corporate\includes\plugins\TCPDF
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($path_to_tcpdf);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

$report_file_doc = DOC_ROOT . '/reports/business_report_U72900GJ2002PTC040573_68628.docx';
$report_file_pdf = DOC_ROOT . '/reports/business_report_U72900GJ2002PTC040573_68628.pdf';



$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($report_file_doc); 
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');

$xmlWriter->save($report_file_pdf);
```

Any idea what could be missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Where/how are you defining `$xmlWriter`?

Comment: if you  are creating both at same time you can use same html instead word document....it may reduce work.....

Comment: Sorry, i have defined $xmlwriter. Have updated the code snippet used

Comment: @kranthi, I am preparing the report from a template file and not HTML. Any idea if we can save the template file into pdf ?

Comment: @Kiran template file means finally we will get html only right....

Comment: why don't you generate the pdf file instead of converting it from word?

Comment: Phpword has horrible conversion to PDF, it uses HTML to generate the pdf so losses nearly all formatting, you can either generate a pdf from scratch or find an alternative to converting word to PDF.

Answer (score 15):

For PHPWord `v0.14`

Here's an example for `TCPDF` renderer (**deprecared in v0.13**):

```
// Require composer autoloder.
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;

// Set PDF renderer.
// Make sure you have `tecnickcom/tcpdf` in your composer dependencies.
Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF);
// Path to directory with tcpdf.php file.
// Rigth now `TCPDF` writer is depreacted. Consider to use `DomPDF` or `MPDF` instead.
Settings::setPdfRendererPath('vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf');

$phpWord = IOFactory::load('document.docx', 'Word2007');
$phpWord->save('document.pdf', 'PDF');
```

Here's an example for `DomPDF` renderer:

```
// Require composer autoloder.
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;

// Make sure you have `dompdf/dompdf` in your composer dependencies.
Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
// Any writable directory here. It will be ignored.
Settings::setPdfRendererPath('.');

$phpWord = IOFactory::load('document.docx', 'Word2007');
$phpWord->save('document.pdf', 'PDF');
```

Comment: It did convert `docx` to `PDF` but didn't preserve styles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'm correct but you save the document as HTML content.After than you read the HTML file content and write the content as PDF file with the help of mPDF or tcPdf or fpdf.

```
 $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
```

[More about it here](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc)

Comment: Found this workaround better. But still, it fails to render the styles and formatting from the word file.